# Android Studio weirdly autoformats blocks in a case

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, case, code-formatting

I have code in Android Studio that I want to look like this:

```
case 0:
    doSomething();
    {
        int x = doSomethingElse();
        doSomethingWithX(x);
    }
    break;
```

But when I format code in Android Studio, it looks like this:

```
case 0:
    doSomething();
{
    int x = doSomethingElse();
    doSomethingWithX(x);
}
break;
```

I've tried in vain to find a setting to fix this, and indenting cases just moves the whole thing. Is there any way I can get Android Studio to format the way I want? What it does makes my code more difficult to follow at a glance.